# Ruby Optional Parameters method calling with one or two

Tags: optional-parameters

The method should return words multiple times. The method should take 2 paramters word and n = number times word should be printed. But I want the second parameter to be optional. I can call the method with single parameter and it should return the same word. If second parameter used then it should return the same word that many times.

```
def repeat(word,n)
    n.times {word}
end
```

`p repeat("abc", 2)` <- this works

but what if I only want

`p repeat("abc")`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had a similar problem today and solved it like this:

```
def repeat(word, n=1)
  n.times {word}
end
```

If you call it like this: 
`p repeat("abc")` it will only repeat it once, but you can pass in a value for n it will repeat however many times you want. If you want it to print out the actual word, this slight modification to the OP's method will do that.

```
def repeat(word, n=1)
  n.times {puts word}
end
```

and call it with `repeat("abc")` or `repeat("abc", 2)`